# noUncheckedIndexedAccess type assertion in array destructuring assignment

Tags: typescript, tuples

With `noUncheckedIndexedAccess`, array accesses now return `T | undefined` to reflect the fact that you might be accessing past `.length`. Sometimes you *know* you aren't and can use a `!` type assertion to tell TypeScript to forget about it.

But I can't figure out how to do that in this case:

```ts
function double(x: number[]): number[] {
  return x.map(a => a * 2)
}

function foo() {
  let a: number = 5;
  let b: number = 6;
  [a, b] = double([b, a]);
}
```

My first guess is

```ts
  [a!, b!] = double([b, a]);
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a non-tedious way to do this?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEziARgGwKYAoAeAXImCALbrYBOA2gLoCUxpF19iA3gFCKJXZQQVJPgB0ZAIYAHXBMQBeAHyI5AKkQAmBlwC+XLqEiwEiYHDi4GnHohxQVzcpSoLEAVgDcNu4nSPWLvKIAGxevDQSADS+dK6oGDi4NOjREoxeOkA)

Comment: Its sort of a pain in the arsenal. Your suppose to be able to override typescript when necessary, but I don't see any way of doing that here, other than turning the setting off. I don't want to turn the setting off because it seems generally accepted as being part of the status-quo strict configuration for TS.

Answer (score 2):

This is a shortcoming of how the `map` method is defined on the `ReadonlyArray` interface in the standard library (and the `ReadonlyArray` interface in general): it returns a mutable array regardless of whether the input type was a tuple or not:

```ts
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: readonly T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[]
}
```

Since the type of values in the `ReadonlyArray` is determined by a generic type parameter `T`, there is no way to determine an exact relationship between indices and values which is essential to being able to return a tuple.

An inherently unsafe, but easy way out using type assertions with `as` was [already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66459381/11407695) (nothing wrong with it per se since your situation is exactly the case where you know more than the compiler does).

Another, safer, but tedious solution you are likely to be aware of is defining your variables as `number | undefined` (a little less tedious if you define a helper `MaybeNum` or similar) and then use type guards to reassure the compiler.

Finally, you can take advantage of the declaration merging technique and provide your own overload for the `map` method that will use `this` inference to get the tuple type. With it, you can return a mapped type in which values are replaced by the inferred `U`:

```ts
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: readonly T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): { [ P in keyof this ] : U };
}
```

Your `double` function now only needs a tweak to tell the compiler that `x` is going to be a `readonly` array:

```ts
const dbl = <T extends readonly number[]>(x: T) => x.map(a => a * 2);
```

The result is exactly what you want (obviously, an `as const` required when you pass an array literal so as it is treated as a tuple, but this is a small price to pay), what's more, the `ReadonlyArray` methods can still be used properly:

```ts
function foo2() {
  let a: number = 5;
  let b: number = 6;
  [a, b] = dbl([b, a] as const); //OK
}

dbl([5,6] as const).forEach((a) => console.log(a)); //OK, a is number here
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=75#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEziARgGwKYAoAeAXImCALbrYBOA2gLoCUxpF19iA3gFCKJXZQQVJPgB0ZAIYAHXBMQBeAHyI5AKkQAmBlwC%20XLjDBRqwCRGyIAStgmowmAJ4BBKlQkOAPABVl3XgHp-SSkPAFVFXAgJTEx0MwBrYDBiXAA3aJBsYi8AGkRDZGwiEnJKKjyJV3diflsER0QvegYFZVC8qAALGABnFwBzAH5iCTAHJkRQ%20gBuHkRgsIiomLiIROTENIysxryCouZS6gqqhxqbOwamxlbJju6%20qiGRsYmORBpEAAV8pHjsBxwYCILq9RB0RDEUKIHSzPRcCAIHpQFBYBSIbyIIrGMDIHp8C71BwlVi0OgRYpeFpKRBiYKyW5qTQMWZcUCQWAIRDAOBwXAtPyIHAoiSHUmIAA%20iHAhWAhmwyHRAFZZrxhYh0GKypLpbjsHKwAr0QA2VUfCR5dAQ%20QoNBYPA0dAVRhw-Ts6DwJA8uAafmcObq0Uk7U2lUBgQarXUE1mmgWjXW1GYXCO50qfGIsDIlm6fTILAppU5Y0QiQZpFQBiiHlUACiZk6uFk1OUmZ6cBwokwcH6zZZiECAHkANIVfL4ljazrUbBAA)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just cast it to a tuple?

```
function double(x: number[]): number[] {
  return x.map(a => a * 2)
}

function foo() {
  let a: number = 5;
  let b: number = 6;
  [a, b] = double([b, a]) as [number, number];
}
```